# Extracting data from tweepy

Tags: python, group-by, append, dataframe, tweepy

I need to collect certain information from somebody's twitter feed (not streaming):
1) Day of the week the reply to another tweet was posted
2) Hour of the day when that reply was posted

What am I doing is:

1) Get the needed information
2) Append that information to the DataFrame
3) Groupby "Day of the week"
4) Go over every day and print a histogram of amount of the replies.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
celebrity = '@elonmusk'

def weekdayf(weekday):
    return{
        0: 'Monday',
        1: 'Tuesday',
        2: 'Wednesday',
        3: 'Thursday',
        4: 'Friday',
        5: 'Saturday',
        6: 'Sunday'
    }[weekday]

data = {'Day of the week': [],
        'Hour': []
       }    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id = celebrity).items(150):
    #find responses
    if status.in_reply_to_status_id != None:
        data = {'Hour': [status.created_at.time().hour],
        'Day of the week': [weekdayf(status.created_at.weekday())]
       }
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df = df.append(df1, ignore_index = True)

df = df.groupby(by = "Day of the week", as_index = True)
```

My questions are:

**I)** My groupby does not work and I don't know why. I used this method before, and had no problem. How do I fix it?

**II)** My friend said that appending is very inefficient. Therefore I must put all the repplies in the dataframe first. 
His suggestions:

```
tweets = [x.__dict__ for x in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id = celebrity).items(10)
         if x.in_reply_to_status_id]
```

Is appending the best way to go? I didn't figure out how to put it all in the DataFrame first. Tweets is a list.

Thank you so much for your help.